# Is there a good OCaml lib for creating a web service like pyramid in python?

Tags: ocaml

The question title says itself.

I find `pyramid` in python is quite easy to use.

In OCaml, I know `Eliom`, but guess it too heavy. And also in client side, I will use `angular js` and don't need to write browser page in OCaml.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use Eliom from [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) ? If you want only HTTP server library, use [ocamlnet](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/ocamlnet.html) !! But it is still off-topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OWebl](http://meetowebl.com/) is a new project that I personally find very promising, and it looks like that it can suite your needs quite well. Other option, is to use [cohttp](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp) directly or with [opium](https://github.com/rgrinberg/opium)

Comment: `cohttp` is a server lib? I thought it is just for client side.

Comment: It provides both a server and a client. But it is quite low-level.

Comment: `OWebl` offers a kind of template, which I won't use as I will use angularjs. Can I just use `njinx` to host static files but use oWebl as to server RESTful?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm also newbie with `OWebl`, didn't touch it myself. In any case, you can always fallback to `cohttp` server.

Comment: btw, another opportunity is to look at `Irmin` database, it has a `REST` API for data. Maybe it will work for you out-of-box, otherwise you can look at how they implemented `REST` api on top of ocamlhttp server.

Answer (score 3):

Eliom doesn't have to be "heavy"; but I think their docs have a slight PR issue there …

Here's a minimal Eliom page that just serves up some HTML from a string when you visit the path `/aaa/bbb` (from https://ocsigen.org/tuto/manual/basicwebsite):

```
let f _ () =
  Lwt.return "<html><head><title>A</title></head><body>B</body></html>"

let main_service =
  Eliom_registration.Html_text.register_service
    ~path:["aaa"; "bbb"]
    ~get_params:Eliom_parameter.any
    f
```

You'll also need a basic config for the server:

```
<ocsigen>
  <server>
    <port>8080</port>

    <charset>utf-8</charset>

    <extension findlib-package="ocsigenserver.ext.staticmod"/>
    <extension findlib-package="ocsigenserver.ext.ocsipersist-dbm"/>
    <extension findlib-package="eliom.server"/>

    <host hostfilter="*">
      <static dir="static" />
      <eliommodule module="_build/foo.cmo" />
      <eliom/>
    </host>
  </server>
</ocsigen>
```

Compile, run the server and try the page:

```
ocamlbuild -pkg eliom.server foo.cmo
ocsigenserver -v -c foo.conf
```

Wait for it to say `ocsigenserver: main: Ocsigen has been launched (initialisations ok)`, then open `http://localhost:8080/aaa/bbb`.

Used that way, it doesn't feel very heavy-weight to me, and you can easily use the minimal parts that you need. That said, without knowing more about what you actually need, it's hard to say whether Eliom is the best choice :-)